# Choosing a median class interval when the median lies on a boundary (not estimating single median value)

Tags: statistics, median

I have a data set with a variable where income tax bands are coded as values. For example, 1 corresponds to the lowest income tax bracket. This means the codes are discrete integer values. I'm using this data to find the median tax bracket based on different filtered cases. In one case, the median is 5.5. What is the appropriate way to deal with this if all I want is a class interval for the median? I don't want an estimation for the exact value, so I don't need to use the formula for estimating the median of grouped data.

The other information I have is that the mean for this variable is > 5.5, but I don't know if that is a robust reason for rounding up to 6 for the tax band. I also have midpoints and upper and lower bounds for all the tax bands, including 5 and 6.

Comment: It seems half your filtered taxpayers are in taxband 5 or lower and half in taxband 6 or higher.  So you could say both 5 and 6 are the median taxbands.  Saying 5.5 has the benefit of being a single number and telling you that you have this equal split even if there is no actual taxband 5.5.

Comment: The requirements are to give ranges (i.e. lower and upper bounds for tax brackets) where possible. Are you suggesting the only way I can do that with any validity is to say the median lies between the lower bound of 5 and the upper bound of 6, giving the median range as "_LB of 5_ - _UB of 6_"?

Comment: No - if you know the boundaries of the bands and these touch, then the median income(?) is exactly the upper boundary of 5 and the lower boundary of 6.  Other cases are then harder: if the median is inside band 5, then getting the exact median needs some calculation

Comment: How can you say with any confidence that the median income is on the boundary when all you know is which band people have said they're in, not precisely how much they earn? This is why we're sticking to ranges. We have no way of knowing that people's incomes are evenly distributed within the class intervals.

Comment: At least half the people are at or below the upper boundary of 5.  At least half the people are at or above the lower boundary of 6.  If these points coincide, it is therefore a median

Comment: If, for example, all the people in band 6 earn barely above the lower bound of band 6, and likewise for the people in band 5, the true median won't be the boundary even if the boundaries coincide. It would be somewhere in band 5. This is why we're sticking to ranges.

Comment: Is the "true median" like a "[true Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)"? The boundary point is a median by the definition of median (half above and half below)

Comment: Maybe use the wider interval containing both.